# Handlebars.js and each helper : problem with buttons

Tags: handlebars.js

I am new with Handlebars.js.
I am using each to display some account.I need to obtain the information of a specific user clicking a button. I will be more specific with the code.

```
{{#each accounts}}

      <div class="form-group">
        <p>{{@index}}</p>
        <label for="name" value={{username}}>{{username}}</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">{{email}}</label>
      </div>
      <button id="myButton">chat</button>


    {{else}}
    <p>No account</p>
    {{/each}}



<script>
  const button = document.getElementById('myButton');
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('button was clicked');
  const number = document.querySelector("p");
   console.log(number);
  });

</script>
```

If I click the first button of the list I can access to the data , however if I try to click the other buttons of the list I can't access to infos.
For example If I click the 3rd button ,I'd like to get the handlebar's information of the 3rd account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an id="myButton" in your loop. IDs should be unique and with your code you'll get as much buttons with id="myButton" as you have accounts. Try to add a class instead if you want to add your event on all buttons.

```
{{#each accounts}}

      <div class="form-group">
        <p>{{@index}}</p>
        <label for="name" value={{username}}>{{username}}</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">{{email}}</label>
      </div>
      <button id="myButton{{@index}}" class="myButton">chat</button>


    {{else}}
    <p>No account</p>
    {{/each}}



<script>
  const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('myButton');
  buttons.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('button was clicked');
  const number = document.querySelector("p");
   console.log(number);
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What do you mean for creating a myButton class?

Comment: to add class="myButton" to the button instead of id="myButton" and also you have to make the id unique by adding (for example) the index of the loop id="myButton{{@index}}"

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I solved the problem. I have one more question for you. How can I access in handlebar to a particular element of an array created with each (Accounts[0].Name , Accounts[1].surname etc..)?

Comment: Do you mean {{accounts.0.name}} and {{accounts.0.surname}} ?